# IF user_signed in? CASE current_user.plan_id ELSE ...?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, case, erb

This 'elegant' helper for showing the user/member status is working perfectly for CASE 1-3 but not working (not showing anything at ERB view <%= user_cat %>) for:

- user.plan_id=NULL

What's the error? How to fix it?

---

```
  def user_cat
    if user_signed_in?
      case current_user.plan_id
      when 1 
        'ESPORÀDIC'
      when 2 
        'FREQÜENT'
      when 3 
        'HABITUAL'
      end 
    else
      'IDENTIFICA\'T'
    end
 end
```

---

*Ruby 2.64 and Rails 6.0.0*

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The NULL case isn't implemented, that's why it renders just nil. But any clue why isn't taking into account the else case in `if user_signed_in?`.

Comment: What did you want to show when current_user.plan_id is NULL? Just add an else clauseafter your last case to deal with that. I'm guessing that if user is not signed in then current_user is nil? so maybe soemthing wrong wth your ` user_signed_in?` method which you do not show so no more help available really

Comment: Thanks Jamesc now it'a working perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

***Thanks!***

```
def user_cat
    if user_signed_in?
      case current_user.plan_id
      when 1 
        'ESPORÀDIC'
      when 2 
        'FREQÜENT'
      when 3 
        'HABITUAL'
      else
        'SUBCRIUTA\'T' 
      end 
     else
      'IDENTIFICA\'T'
    end
  end
```